# Arbitrary criteria for megastructures?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction

Another question based around my story of a modern take on the Asimovian "galactic empire" concept.

A few things (some of you already know this now, sorry for the repetition) about this empire just for clarification:

1. FTL is impossible. Stable wormholes of an instant, portal-like nature exist at the boundaries of solar systems through which ships travel.
2. No classic "alien civilization" has yet been discovered, though things passingly acknowledged as intelligent in the sense we regard earth's dolphins have been encountered occasionally.
3. While there are no civilized aliens, let alone humanoid ones (which wouldn't happen anyhow), genetic drift (sometimes deliberate in some cultures) has diversified humanity a good bit more than the limited racial diversity currently on earth.
4. Energy problems don't exist - fusion has been entirely mastered.

My question:

All of this should qualify this as a Kardashev 2 civilization, going on Kardashev 3. However, as a literary and worldbuilding choice, I want to refrain from megastructures such as Dyson Swarms being the fate of every system humans colonize.

Is it a realistic notion to believe that in many cases, a local colony system's culture would elect to keep the system intact. Thus, happy to expand within their system in artificial habitats made out of only the "rubble" in a system such as meteors, and digging into the otherwise uninhabitable worlds of a system in the manner we'd likely colonize the moon and so on in the near future? A desire to preserve more interesting solar systems the way we like to preserve natural beauty on earth?

If so, what might the usual criteria people would set for "we shouldn't dismantle this solar system" be? What would prompt others to dismantle theirs? Would it just be an arbitrary choice made based on the sensibilities of the culture in that system, or would a larger pattern of when that does or does not happen emerge?

Comment: "Stable wormholes of an instant, portal-like nature exist at the boundaries of solar systems through which ships travel" - how does this not instantly result in FTL?

Comment: I would imagine the following way:

1) Some objects are protected by imperial law, thus unless there is a really good reason they are left intact. It's a bit tricky what would be considered as rarity / worth protection / etc. My guesses:

a) planets where life evolved (or abiogenisis is starting), their moon system, etc.

b) planets on some really uncommon orbits (like horseshoe orbit)

c) unexplored planets (first explore, then dissasembly permit)


2) The rest - colony decision.

Comment: d) planets of high historical significance  e) Chthonian planet?

Comment: @Aify Well, you can't open them arbitrarily - they're unpredictable as to where they open to. They have no idea where, relative to one another, the colony worlds are. Some may be on the other side of the known (or even unknown) universe.

Comment: I know it's a courtesy to wait 24 hours before accepting an answer usually, but since my question got put on hold (which I usually wouldn't argue with but feel in this case, wasn't completely called for ...), it means nobody else can answer it anyhow. And since rewording the question would make it not the question I asked ... I'm just going to go ahead and accept the answer Keelhaul provided. It's 99% exactly what I needed anyhow. Apologies for violating the 24 hour wait just this once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You don't destroy half your home to build a pool.

My guess is that it would mostly depends on the available materials. Dyson swarms require massive amounts of matter (and work), so the question would be "Is there enough planets and moons to destroy to get a nice Dyson swarm while keeping some natural space for us to live on ?". If your swarm is only used to gather the star energy, while

> Energy problems don't exist - fusion has been entirely mastered.

... it would be only useful if you have a really great expense of energy in your system to account for, i.e. many people (and therefore planets/moons required) to feed, house and entertain.

Imagine you have a big house with a large terrain. You can build a pool and a tennis court in this terrain. You'll have a little less surface for running around and making barbecue with your friends, but there's still plenty of room, and a pool and a tennis court are nice things to have. On the other hand, if you have a small house with a small terrain, you won't destroy half of your house to make room for the pool. A pool is nice, but the habitable surface is better.